# Finding Maximum likelihood estimator of a function

Tags: statistics, summation, absolute-value, maximum-likelihood

5. (8 pts) The random variables $X_1$, $X_2$, $\ldots$, $X_n$ are independent each with the distribution $$f_X (x; b, m) = \frac{1}{2b}e^{−|x−m|/b} \text{ for } −\infty < x < \infty.$$ 
   Find the Maximum Likelihood estimators for $b$ and $m$ given the sample: $−2.2, −1.7, −.8, .4, 1.2, 2.4, 3.3, 4.1$, and $10.4$.

I managed to get to the $\ln$ term which was

$$n\ln\left(\frac{1}{2b}\right)-\frac1b \sum |x_i-m|$$

Don't know where to go from here

Comment: See Wikipedia on Laplace distribution.

Comment: $n\ln\left(\frac{1}{2b}\right) = n\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) - n\ln\left(b\right)$ and has an easy derivative with respect to $b$